# How do we use session to hold multiple bean object?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to create a simple JSP form to accept details of student. Store it in bean. Then add this bean in to session. On click of display it should show as many bean I have added in session...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bean student;// intialized with required values

session.setAttribute(student);
```

That should set the value of your student bean to the session